# Using multiple laser scans for gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, laser, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to do the SLAM mapping with gmapping on my robot, which has 2 lasers on it, in the font and in the back of the robot. So how can I use 2 laser scans for gmapping, since gmapping only subscribes 1 /scan topic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387733/using-multiple-laser-scans-for-gmapping/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-01**:
Search for fusion of data sensors like in question /#q273572

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-10-01**:
Thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-03**:
You can also do a search on `merge scans` in the dialog box at the top of this page, and you will get a lot of hits. If you find a solution that someone else made that works for you, you can help out the community by answering your own question and providing a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Mike Scheutzow's help, I have merged my scans for gmapping, by following this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/273572/how-to-use-ira_laser_tools-package-to-merge-laser-datas/). it worked like a charm, using two lidars helps the mapping process much faster and as accurate as using only one lidar.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) with karma: 58 on 2021-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-03**:
I'm glad you found a solution.

The question you point at appears to use the `laserscan_multi_merger` from https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools